# Fetch data via JSON parser with thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xcode, web-services, json

i am stuck in one problem regarding JSON parser.actually i am fetching data through JSON parser and it works successfully but i want to display that data as it come one by one and so that i need to work with Thread so anybody can help me out?how to use multiple thread while fetching data

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `NSOperation`. It is the easiest way to perform Network operations in separate threads. The documentation can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: :i have gone through this link and try to run the sample project but none of the project run successfully..is there any other way?

Comment: What is the error you are facing? NSOperation is one of the most widely used methods for these operations. If you want to get your hands dirty, you can create threads yourself (see NSThread) & manage data between them yourself. You will have to take care of synchronization to tackle race conditions.

Comment: frankly speaking i haven't work on thread and with json parser till now.so it will be appreciate if your explain it with detail or with any example.

Comment: As I told you, `NSOperation` is the simplest option that you have. It will manage threads & everything itself. Try searching for its tutorials & go slow. Don't think that you will copy a snippet from the web & things will work automatically.